# Override settings in django tests

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-testing, django-tests

I try to:

```
 @override_settings(EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='sdsds')
 def  test_email_not sent(self):
   ....
```

I want to brake down Django SMTP settings and test, but setting didn't get overrided.

Comment: What does your settings file look like?

Comment: what you mean standard django setting. `SETTING_NAME ='string'`. In my case `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='my_password'`, `EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'` And i want to put wrong pass or smpt, to broke the email sending system.

Comment: How are you checking that the setting is not overriden? Can you update your entire test method with the asserts and the exact error/issue?

Comment: ok 10 min, i guess the view that send email is bad not my test

Answer (score 1):

By default, Django uses a local memory backend for emails when testing. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#email-services) for more info.

If you want to use the smtp backend, you can override the setting.

```
@override_settings(EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend', EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='sdsds')
 def  test_email_not sent(self):
     ...
```